# Diff in Diff with panel dataset on R

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a panel dataset that I'd like to conduct diff in diff on. Right now this is my regression:

```
fit3 <- glm(df$empstat ~ factor(year) + factor(stateicp) + migrant_category + treated*post + treated*migrant_category
           + post*migrant_category + treated*post*migrant_category + race + educ + age +
             marst, data = df, weights = perwt, family = 'gaussian'
)
```

but will this make R assume that each observation is independent of each other? If yes, what should I do to make R realize that this is a panel data?

Comment: You can do diff-in-diff with panel with `plm`, check example https://rpubs.com/phle/r_tutorial_difference_in_differences or https://github.com/PrisonRodeo/GSERM-Ljubljana-APD-git/blob/main/Code/GSERM-Ljubljana-2023-DayFour.R But I think your question is aiming at another `glm` (employment status?). A minimal data examples would have been great. The authors have done another package `pglm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in fixed effects models and difference in difference, use the `plm` package. Here is an example from Christopher Zorn:

```
# Panel data 
WDI<-read_csv("https://github.com/PrisonRodeo/GSERM-Ljubljana-APD-git/raw/main/Data/WDI3.csv")

# Add a "Cold War" variable:
WDI$ColdWar <- with(WDI,ifelse(Year<1990,1,0))

# Keep a numeric year variable (for -panelAR-):
WDI$YearNumeric<-WDI$Year

# Make the data a panel dataframe:
WDI<-pdata.frame(WDI,index=c("ISO3","Year"))

# Pull out *only* those countries that, at some
# point during the observed periods, instituted
# a paid parental leave policy:
WDI<-WDI %>% group_by(ISO3) %>%
  filter(any(PaidParentalLeave==1))

# Create a better trend variable:
WDI$Time<-WDI$YearNumeric-1950

# FE models...

fe1<-plm(ChildMortality~PaidParentalLeave+Time+
                  PaidParentalLeave*Time,data=WDI,
                effect="individual",model="within")

fe2<-plm(ChildMortality~PaidParentalLeave+Time+
                  PaidParentalLeave*Time+log(GDPPerCapita)+
                  log(NetAidReceived)+GovtExpenditures,
                data=WDI,effect="individual",model="within")

fe3<-plm(ChildMortality~PaidParentalLeave+Time+
                  PaidParentalLeave*Time,data=WDI,
                effect="twoway",model="within")

fe4<-plm(ChildMortality~PaidParentalLeave+Time+
                  PaidParentalLeave*Time+log(GDPPerCapita)+
                  log(NetAidReceived)+GovtExpenditures,
                data=WDI,effect="twoway",model="within")

# TABLE TIME

stargazer(fe1,fe2,fe3,fe4,
          title="DiD Models of log(Child Mortality)",
          column.separate=c(1,1,1),align=TRUE,
          dep.var.labels.include=FALSE,
          dep.var.caption="",
          covariate.labels=c("Paid Parental Leave","Time (1950=0)",
                                           "Paid Parental Leave x Time",
                                           "ln(GDP Per Capita)",
                                           "ln(Net Aid Received)",
                                           "Government Expenditures"),
                        header=FALSE,model.names=FALSE,
                        model.numbers=FALSE,multicolumn=FALSE,
                        object.names=TRUE,notes.label="",
                        column.sep.width="-15pt",
                        omit.stat=c("f","ser"),type="text")

DiD Models of log(Child Mortality)
=====================================================================
                              fe1        fe2        fe3        fe4   
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Paid Parental Leave        -15.500*** -26.200*** -12.500*** -17.300* 
                            (2.420)    (7.220)    (2.960)    (9.360) 
                                                                     
Time (1950=0)              -0.838***  -1.480***                      
                            (0.025)    (0.094)                       
                                                                     
Paid Parental Leave x Time            -7.110***              -4.910* 
                                       (2.290)               (2.600) 
                                                                     
ln(GDP Per Capita)                    -1.780***             -3.020***
                                       (0.471)               (0.552) 
                                                                     
ln(Net Aid Received)                   0.873***             0.842*** 
                                       (0.139)               (0.146) 
                                                                     
Government Expenditures     0.310***   0.524***   0.247***   0.319*  
                            (0.044)    (0.128)    (0.056)    (0.169) 
                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                 2,360       622       2,360       622   
R2                           0.496      0.717      0.009      0.143  
Adjusted R2                  0.485      0.701      -0.035     0.014  
=====================================================================
                                          *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```